# C# fileSystemWatcher, Adding File names into Listbox Problem

Tags: filesystemwatcher

I'm using fileSystemWatcher for new files in to folder then I add their file names to a listbox. Program can dedect new files successfully but I'm facing problem adding file names into listbox since it adds same file names a couple of times if multiple files added into folder at same time. My codes are herebelow.

File Names : 1,2,3,4,
Listbox output: 2,3,2,3,2,3,4,1,2,3,4

```
      void watcher_FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
      {
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
       
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            folderlist.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the reason of the problem, I found a solution to avoid problem. I just checked whether item is already exist in the listbox. If not, add into listbox.

```
void watcher_FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
   
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        if (!folderlist.Items.Contains(file.Name))
        {
             folderlist.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }
  }
```